# Android webview & javaScriptInterface like functionality in NativeScript to save session token using login webpage in webview

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript

In android if I want to use an already existing login webpage, I can use webview and javaScriptInterface to save token values after login success. Is there a similar functionality to save the token values using the pre-existing login webpage in NativeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `application settings` module.

```
var appSettings = require("application-settings");

//Save the token
appSettings.setString("token",token)

//Retrieve token
var token = appSettings.getString("token");
```

Data is persistent until user uninstalls the app.